# C# WinForms: Constructing an object with label/textbox properties in a form does not result in those properties appearing in the form. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

What I'm doing is: I have an object which initializes its textbox/label contents in the constructor, however when the object is constructed in its intended form I can't make the contents appear on the form. An example:

```
public ProductEntry(int value){
       this.productdesc = new TextBox
       {
        Location = new Point(x,y), 
        Width = 30,
        Height = 30,
       };
       }
```

I tried adding visibility tags but that wasn't it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you add the textbox to the form? You also don't seem to have added any text to it?

Comment: I'm pretty new to C#, do I have to construct a seperate TextBox using these properties in the form? This particular textbox is intended for input so I didn't add any text

Comment: I recommend you to check the .Designer.cs to see, what is actually done, when adding controls to the form.

Comment: You just need to add it to the form, like the answer below. More commonly though people add the boxes to the form using the designer. If it shouldn't be shown immediately then you can set it to be invisible. The only reason really to do what you're doing here is if you need to construct an unknown number of text boxes on the fly based on some calculations

Comment: @ADyson that is exactly what I'm after so I resorted to this sort of solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this control to a form - like so:

```
YourForm.Controls.Add(productdesc);
```

Which is described in a greater detail here: https://support.microsoft.com/pl-pl/help/319266/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-windows-forms-at-run-time-by-u

Comment: as a hint: you could create a "small" winform solution, let´s say with 2 textboxes and two labels, and then analyze the designer generated code. I´m pretty sure you will find this enlighting